# Unknown Column in Where Clause When Using the Variable Created with AS

Tags: mysql, where-clause

The question is about using a column (which is created in query) as where clause criteria.

There are 2 tables named transactions and transactionmovements.

In transaction, there are unique info for transaction like date, counterparty etc.

In transactionmovements, there are articles which is used in transaction. Such as product, quantity, price, etc. And transactionmovements has a 'transaction' column which references to transactions.id shows which transaction the movement belongs.

In the query, I created a totalPrice value with sum of quantity*price of each movement that belongs to a transaction.

Everything works perfectly but the last parameter of WHERE clause. If I delete "AND 
totalPrice > 10" part, it gives me everything including totalPrice and totalQuantity of a transaction.
But if I place "AND totalPrice > 10" to the end, it returns following error:

-#1054 - Unknown column 'totalPrice' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT 
`transactions`.id, 
`transactions`.type, 
`transactions`.date, 
`transactions`.VAT, 
`transactions`.currency, 
`companies`.name AS counterparty, 
COALESCE
(sum(`transactionmovements`.price*`transactionmovements`.quantity)
+(`transactions`.shippingQuantity*`transactions`.shippingPrice)) as totalPrice, 
COALESCE
(sum(`transactionmovements`.quantity)) as totalQuantity 
FROM 
`transactions` 
LEFT JOIN `companies` ON `transactions`.counterparty = `companies`.id 
LEFT JOIN `transactionmovements` ON `transactions`.id=`transactionmovements`.transaction 
WHERE ( `transactions`.type = 'p' OR `transactions`.type = 'r' OR `transactions`.type = 's' OR `transactions`.type = 't') 
AND 
(`transactions`.date BETWEEN IFNULL('','1900-01-01') AND IFNULL('2020-02-14',NOW())) 
AND 
totalPrice > 10 
GROUP BY `transactions`.id 
ORDER BY id desc 
LIMIT 10
```

I tried using the whole math operation in WHERE clause, but no gains. I tried to use HAVING with WHERE but couldn't manage it.

The last solution I have is running it without filtering by totalPrice and store it into a php array. Then filter in array, but there I can't use LIMIT so array will be very big.

Comment: You can NOT use output field alias in WHERE clause (but may in HAVING). Moreover - WHERE removes some rows before GROUP BY whereas the value of a field which you want to use for removing is formed/calculated only after grouping (and so it affects on all output values, including self). Your query logic is somewhere wrong with guarantee (TL;DR).

Comment: try creating view, then call the view and applied the where clause

Answer (score 0):

As per how [SQL query are executed in the order](https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution) that dictate `SELECT` is executed after `WHERE`, you can't use ALIAS in WHERE since it is unknown at the moment. Therefor, you should change every alias uses outside of SELECT to its definition.

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas Jeriko suggested in comments, creating a view was exactly what I need.
First I create a virtual table with Create View.

```
CREATE VIEW transactionreportview
    AS SELECT 
        transactions.id id, 
        transactions.type type,
        transactions.date date,
        transactions.VAT VAT,
        transactions.currency currency,
        transactions.counterparty counterparty, 
        (SUM(transactionmovements.price*transactionmovements.quantity)+transactions.shippingQuantity*transactions.shippingPrice) totalPrice,
        SUM(transactionmovements.quantity) totalQuantity
    FROM transactions transactions, transactionmovements transactionmovements
    WHERE transactions.id = transactionmovements.transaction
    GROUP BY transactions.id;
```

While the virtual table acts like a simple mysql table, I ran a new query in the table

```
SELECT * FROM transactionReportView WHERE ..."
```

Then after finishing my work with the virtual table, drop it

```
DROP VIEW transactionreportview
```